# How to remove extra new line character?

Tags: linux, newline

I've big file having records like below

```
ZZZ4155HJJHH
ZZZJHHGBHJBH
ZZZjJHJHHHJB
ZZZJBH
HBHHBHBH
ZZZJBJBJHBH
ZZZJJNJNJJJ
```

As you can see, 4th record is split into two lines

How can I move 5th line back to 4th line to complete record in single line ?

Expected output

```
ZZZ4155HJJHH
ZZZJHHGBHJBH
ZZZjJHJHHHJB
ZZZJBHHBHHBHBH
ZZZJBJBJHBH
ZZZJJNJNJJJ
```

Comment: How to __detect__ an extra newline? Can you give an exact rule? "If this and that, then that means this is an extra newline"? What have you tried? What research did you do?

Comment: Is the rule: combine any line not starting with ZZZ with the previous line?